# how to remove a letter according to a particular position

Tags: php

i have two php files.
1st is displayPhone.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
$labels=array("first_name"=>"First Name",
                "last_name"=>"Last Name",
                "phone"=>"Phone");
?>
<body>
<h3>please enter your phone number below</h3>
<form action='savePhone2.php' method='POST'>
<?php
//loop that displays the form field
foreach($labels as $field =>$value)
{
    echo "$field <input type='text' name='$field' size='65' maxlenghth='65'/><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit phone number'/>";
?>
```

2nd is savePhone2.php

```
<?php
$labels=array("first_name"=>"First Name",
                "last_name"=>"Last Name",
                "phone"=>"Phone");
?>
<body>
<?php
foreach($_POST as $field =>$value)
{
    if(empty($value))
    {
        $blank_array[]=$field;
    }
    elseif(preg_match("/name/i",$field))
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z' -]{1,50}$/",$value))
        {
            $bad_format[]=$field;
        }
    }
    elseif($field=="phone")
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$/",$value))
        {
            $bad_format[]=$field;
        }
    }
}

if(@sizeof($blank_array)>0 or  @sizeof($bad_format)>0)
{
    if(@sizeof($blank_array)>0)
    {
        echo "<p>input";
        foreach($blank_array as $value)
        {
        echo " $labels[$value]";
        }
        echo "</p>";
    }

    if(@sizeof($bad_format)>0)
    {
        echo "<p>invalid format";
        foreach($bad_format as $value)
        {
            echo $labels[$value];
        }
        echo "</p>";
    }

//redisplay form
    echo "<hr/>";
    echo "enter phone number";
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";

    foreach($labels as $field =>$label)
    {
        $good_data[$field]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$field]));
        echo "$label <input type='text' name='$field' size='65' maxlength='65' value='$good_data[$field]'/><br/>";  
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' value='submit phone number'/>";
exit();
}
else
{
    $user='root';
    $host='localhost';
    $password='root';
    $dbname='pet';
    $cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("can't connect to server");
    foreach($labels as $field =>$value)
        {
            $good_data[$field]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$field]));
            $good_data[$field]=mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$good_data[$field]);
        }
    $check_exist="SELECT ";
    foreach($labels as $field =>$value)
    {
        $check_exist.=$field.",";
    }
    $check_exist=preg_replace("/,{3}/","",$check_exist);
    $check_exist.=" FROM data WHERE ";
    foreach($good_data as $field =>$value)
    {
        $check_exist.=$field."="; $check_exist.="'$value'".",";
    }
    echo $check_exist;
```

Iam having a problem that i don't know how to remove the decimals at `phone,` and at `phone='0123456789087'`, on this query:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,phone, FROM data WHERE
    first_name='sloth',last_name='dig',phone='0123456789087',
```

Comment: `i don't know how to remove the points at "phone,"...` -- I don't understand. What do you mean by *points*?

Comment: Why are you specifying your AND statements with commas? So much as I know that's invalid. SELECT first_name,last_name,phone, FROM data WHERE first_name='sloth' AND last_name='dig' AND phone='0123456789087' - AND could also be OR. I don't know which you were hoping for here

Comment: i mean the "," letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to take control of trailing characters when build a string from list is by joining prepared elements of an array.

Change

```
 $check_exist="SELECT ";
 foreach($labels as $field =>$value)
     {
         $check_exist.=$field.",";
     }
```

to

```
 $check_exist="SELECT ";
 $fieldArray = array();
 foreach($labels as $field =>$value)
     {
         $fieldArray[] = $field;
     }
 $check_exist .= join(', ', $fieldArray);
```

In the same manner you could change

```
foreach($good_data as $field =>$value)
    {
        $check_exist.=$field."="; $check_exist.="'$value'".",";
    }
```

to

```
$whereArray = array();
foreach($good_data as $field =>$value)
    {
        $whereArray[] = $field . "=" . "'$value'";
    }
$check_exist .= join(' AND ', $whereArray);
```

This should produce `SELECT first_name, last_name, phone FROM data WHERE
    first_name='sloth' AND last_name='dig' AND phone='0123456789087'` - notice that after `where` conditions are joined by `AND` rather than a comma `,`.
And of course this will work only if `$good_data` and `$labels` are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question.

Do you mean that there are decimal points (periods, dots) in the phone number when retrieved from the database and you wish to remove them?

[phpFiddle here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/h0w-1v1)

If so:

```
<?php
$n = "123.456.7890";
$o = str_replace(".", "", $n);
echo $o;

$x = "123,456,7890";
$y = str_replace(",", "", $x);
echo $y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may continue to use your code

```
foreach($good_data as $field =>$value)
{
    $check_exist.=$field."="; $check_exist.="'$value'".",";
}
```

and clean $check_exists at the end

```
$check_exists = rtrim($check_exists, ",");
```